# Python - Does the string contain a specific string within brackets?

Tags: python

I am trying to find out if a string contains `[city.----]` and where the `----` is, any city could be in there. I just want to make sure it's formatted correctly. I've been searching for how I can ask Python to ignore that `----` but with no luck. Here is an example on how I would like to use this in the code:

```
if "[city.----]" in mystring:
    print 'success'
```

Comment: So you're searching for [city.<any characters allowed here>]?

Comment: `mystring.startswith('[city.') and mystring.endswith(']')`

Comment: Are you looking for something like a regex?

Comment: Ys, I'm looking for: [city.<any characters allowed here>]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`str.startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`str.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
if mystring.startswith('[city.') and mystring.endswith(']'):
    print 'success'
```

Alternatively, you can use [python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
if mystring[:6] == '[city.' and mystring[-1:] == ']':
    print 'success'
```

Lastly, you can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
if re.search(r'^\[city\..*?\]$', mystring) is not None:
    print 'success'
```

Comment: You could improve on the regular expression by making it either non-greedy (`.*?`) or by matching everything *except* a closing bracket (`[^\]]*`) instead of all characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try something using [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module (Here's the [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) about regular expressions).

```
>>> import re

>>> x = "asalkjakj [city.Absul Hasa Hii1] asjad a" # good string
>>> y = "asalkjakj [city.Absul Hasa Hii1 asjad a" # wrong string
>>> print re.match ( r'.*\[city\..*\].*', x )
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1064ad578>
>>> print re.match ( r'.*\[city\..*\].*', y )
None
```